# Script to duplicate Debian setup?

Tags: linux, debian

I know I have a bash history of commands run on a server setup which I can use for a sort-of setup guide on cloning the same type of cloud server elsewhere, but settings done in nano would obviously not show.

Is there an easy way of scripting a setup from an existing server (that I didn't setup) and copy the configs over to another server?

We don't have the luxury of puppet at the moment.

Comment: like `sudo tar -cf- /  | nc somehost 9999` and `nc -l 9999 | sudo tar -C/ -xf-`...?

Comment: maybe not realistic. this could be better: `mkdir /tmp/root mount -B / /tmp/root; mksquashfs /tmp/root /tmp/root.sfs`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're suggesting there but I will go google and see if it's what I'm attempting. Maybe I should just manually run the bash history and transfer the nginx/mysql configs and hope for the best that I don't forget anything

Comment: im just suggesting you copy `/`.

Comment: Ah I see, if the Debian versions differ, would that be a problem?